# How to destroy window and create it again?

Tags: mfc

I have created a window
When I do this

```
w->Create (...);
w->DestroyWindow ();
w->Create (...);
```

The program crashes
Can any one help?

Comment: Since we don't know how *your* `DestroyWindow` is implemented, or what's in your `WM_DESTROY` and `WM_NCDESTROY` handlers, we cannot provide much help, besides the obvious: Learn how to use a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

We don't know enough about your MFC window class.  If it is derived from CFrameWnd or CView, it is going to crash. That is because after those windows are destroyed, their C++ memory pointer (this) is not valid anymore.  It points to an area of memory that has been freed by the C++ memory allocator.  Attempting to dereference it will cause a crash.  Because, in the PostNcDestroy() overrides, the CFrameWnd and CView classes call "delete this".

```
void CFrameWnd::PostNcDestroy()
{
    // default for frame windows is to allocate them on the heap
    //  the default post-cleanup is to 'delete this'.
    // never explicitly call 'delete' on a CFrameWnd, use DestroyWindow instead
    delete this;
}

void CView::PostNcDestroy()
{
    // default for views is to allocate them on the heap
    //  the default post-cleanup is to 'delete this'.
    //  never explicitly call 'delete' on a view
    delete this;
}
```